# JUnit 5 tests don't work in the Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

I'm trying to run a Unit test in a Spring Boot project.
Here pom.xml

```html
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.12</version>

    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>ru.home</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-first-devops</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-first-devops</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <description>my-first-devops</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
    <org.springframework-version>5.3.1</org.springframework-version>
    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>

    <junit.jupiter.version>5.8.1</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.8.1</junit.platform.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>
            --illegal-access=permit
          </argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>
            --illegal-access=permit
          </argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>
```

At the root of the folder
test
java
there is a file created by Spring itself

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyFirstDevopsApplicationTests {
//    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

And in the folder
test
java
service
My class with a test

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
class UserServiceTest {
    private UserService userService;
    @Test
    void usersEmptyIfNoUserAdded() {
        var users = userService.getAll();
        assertTrue(users.isEmpty());
    }
}

mvn test
```

does not find any test.
If you run this class from IDEA by selecting run User Service Test, it throws an error:

```
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
```

I tried to add all the dependencies as shown on this site:
[JUnit 5 Maven Dependency](https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/junit5-maven-dependency/)

then

```
mvn test
```

returns an error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project my-first-devops: There are test failures.
```

Change pom.xml

```html
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.12</version>

    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>ru.home</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-first-devops</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-first-devops</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <description>my-first-devops</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>

    <junit.jupiter.version>5.8.1</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.8.1</junit.platform.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

But it didn't help.

```
mvn test
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Start by not trying to outsmart the framework. Remove the plugins you configured. Remove the `junit` exclusion and your dedicated dependencies for JUnit5. Than run everything again. If you really want to use a certain JUnit5 version just include a property for that in the `properties` section, the `junit-jupiter.version` property. Spring BOot will then pull in that version for you. Also don't use Spring 5.3.1 with Spring BOot 2.4 as that will, at some point, bite you as the version used and depended upon is higher.

Comment: Deleted as you wrote, but it didn't help.

Comment: Problem is non-reproducible with the information you gave. I had to remove the version limitations you had in your Pom as it is not valid and it works for me

Comment: You didn't change as I wrote. You still have the compiler plugin (I said to remove the plugins), I also said to remove the junit dependencies and let Spring Boot manage them. Also your second error clearly shows that tests are found but that there are test errors (fix those errors as well). `UserServiceTest` will fail with a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: M. Deinum - I deleted the plugin - it didn't help.

Comment: SirHawrk - I deleted the version, and the test passed. But why? I had the latest version 5.8.1 specified. What was the error here?

Comment: It works with this version <junit.jupiter.version>5.7.2</junit.jupiter.version>

Comment: You should edit your question with the new information you have gathered. Also if you wanna tag someone add a "@" in front of their name so they get a notification. With your other question. I am not certain, I will have to look that up

Comment: Works with 5.8.1 as well